# Why the default gc generation threshold is set to (700, 10, 10) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection, python-internals

Why the default GC generation threshold is set to **[(700, 10, 10)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/gcmodule.c#L64)** in Python; And the latter two numbers **10, 10** are so small?

Does such low threshold would result in much more collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thresholds are **multipliers** relative to the *previous generation*. From the [`gc.set_threshold()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold):

> In order to decide when to run, the collector keeps track of the number object allocations and deallocations since the last collection. When the number of allocations minus the number of deallocations exceeds `threshold0`, collection starts. Initially only generation `0` is examined. **If generation `0` has been examined more than `threshold1` times since generation `1` has been examined, then generation `1` is examined as well. Similarly, `threshold2` controls the number of collections of generation `1` before collecting generation `2`.**

*Bold emphasis mine.*

So generation 1 is only run if generation 0 has been run 10 times. Since generation 0 only runs every 700 (delta of allocation - deallocation) cycles, that means generation 1 is run every 10 * 700 == 7.000 cycles. Generation 2 is run every 10 * 10 * 700 == 70.000 cycles.

Comment: So what happens if your app is creating small objects too fast? E.g. you allocate 700 objects, 8 bytes each. This is only 5Kb of RAM. Python will repeat the garbage collection after each of these series is created? It's quite surprising that Python's GC considers only the number of objects, but not the overall heap size left.

Comment: Yes, the docs say _"When the number of allocations minus the number of deallocations exceeds threshold0, collection starts"_. I meant what will happen if you _don't_ deallocate those 700 objects, but continue to allocate more items. Let's substitute this to the formula: number of allocations is 700, number of deallocations is 0. 700 minus zero is 700. The threshold0 is met (after 5Kb). So with continuous allocations of small objects Python GC will run after each 5Kb of data.

Comment: @DmitryK sorry, yes, the gc runs after 700 objects have been created with 0 deallocations because if there were 700 circular references (which would prevent reallocations) you’d want those cleared ASAP. If you are creating a large number of small objects and know there are no circular references, just disable the gc until you are done bulk allocating.

Comment: @DmitryK know that no Python object is ever only 8 bytes. On a 64-bit architecture the size of the object metadata alone will be 16 bytes.  If they are instances with a `__dict__`: 64 bytes plus the attributes (keys and values count separately) plus any over-allocation for amortised future expansion. 700 objects is going to be closer to ~150kb.